# How to run a Javascript query on data that is being received from a database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on a very important project and I'm almost done.
But I'm stuck on the final part of the core function of the website... I want to know how to retrieve data from three columns: "Title", "Description", "Link" from my database and print the "Title" and "Description" rows to a `<div></div>` and i want to use the `$("#anchor").attr("href", link)` to the link attribute `<div><a href = "" id = "anchor"></a></div>` my problem is that it only executes the Javascript code on the first row in the database table.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>test001</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    #load1 {
      background-color: green;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
    }
    
    #load2 {
      background-color: green;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
    }
  </style>

  <div id="divone">
    <div id="load">
      <div id="load1">

      </div>
      <div id="load2">

      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="" id="load3" target="_ blank">
                    Test
                </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    function clone() {
      var div = document.getElementById("load");
      var cln = div.cloneNode(true);
      document.getElementById("divone").appendChild(cln);
    }
  </script>
  <?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id5757217_testsql01", "9977553311", "id5757217_testsql1");
              // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM insertion";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   // output data of each row
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
            $array[] = $row;
            $id = $row['ID'];
            $tle = $row['Title'];
            $des = $row['Description'];
            $lnk = $row['Link'];
            echo "<script type = text/javascript>clone()</script>";
}

} else { echo "0 results"; }
            $conn->close();
 ?>

    <script>
      var id = "<?php echo $id; ?>";
      var title = "<?php echo $tle; ?>";
      $("#load1").text(title);
      var desc = "<?php echo $des; ?>";
      $("#load2").text(desc);
      var lnk = "<?php echo $lnk; ?>";
      $("#load3").attr("href", lnk);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your `clone()` function is creating duplicate IDs. IDs have to be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're echo-ing only one row because your echo is outside your `while` loop:

You need to move your `echo` for the data back into the loop IE

```
echo " <script>";
 while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
        $array[] = $row;
        $id = $row['ID'];
        $tle = $row['Title'];
        $des = $row['Description'];
        $lnk = $row['Link'];
        echo "clone();";
        echo 'var id = "' . $id . '";';
        echo 'var title = "' . $tle . '";';
        echo '$("#load1").text(title);';
        echo 'var desc = "' . $des . '";';
        echo '$("#load2").text(desc);';
        echo 'var lnk = "' . $lnk . '";';
        echo '$("#load3").attr("href", lnk);';
}

} else { echo "0 results"; }
        $conn->close();
        echo "</script>";
```

**update**

Also as Barmar stated in comment, you'll be overwriting the text for `$("#load1")` every iteration of the loop.  In order to "see" this working .. I'd use `$("#load1").append()` so you can at least "view" what you are doing and change your code accordingly  -- OR -- Create the elements dynamically, and use a `key` to name them.

Comment: He's also creating duplicate IDs. `$("#load1").html()` is going to overwrite the same element each time through the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using Javascript to create all the DIVs. Just do it in the PHP script itself.

You also need to change all your duplicate IDs to classes, since IDs are supposed to be unique.

```
<div id="divone">
    <?php
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
        <div class="load">
            <div class="load1"> <?php echo $row['Title']; ?> </div>
            <div class="load2"> <?php echo $row['Description']; $> </div>
            <div> <a class="load3" href="<?php echo $row['Link']; ?>" target="_blank">Test</a> </div>
        </div>
        <?php }
?>
</div>
```